# How to compute a property value based on other property values "inline" during creation of JS object literal?

Tags: javascript

I want to compute the `full` property as a result of the `first` and `last` properties in a single step, like so:

```
const name = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  full: `${this.first} ${this.last}`, // undefined
}
```

But `name.full` is `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `full: \`${name.first} ${name.last}\``

Comment: The problem is that `this` still refers to `window`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const name = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  get full() {
     return `${this.first} ${this.last}`;
  }
}
console.log(name.full);
```